# Issue while loading data into form field which is returned using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have form layout where i am loading city details like city name, state
 and country   depending on City id and is returned via JSON.

Function for the same as follow:

```
public JsonResult GetCityDetails(int city_id)
    {
        var result = "SELECT (CITY_NAME + ', ' + STATE_NAME + ', ' + COUNTRY_NAME) AS CITY_NAME FROM COUNTRY_MASTER cm, STATE_MASTER sm, CITY_MASTER cy where cy.STATE_ID = sm.STATE_ID AND sm.COUNTRY_ID = cm.COUNTRY_ID AND cy.CITY_ID =" + city_id + " ";
        var tempPerson = DatabaseHelper.Instance.Database.QuerySingle(result);
        return Json(new { Data = tempPerson.CITY_NAME });
    }
```

Here, i am getting correct data for city details which is returned via JSON, but issue while loading into html form field.

However, this function is called in java script function as follow:

```
loadCityDetails: function (_cityid) {
           debugger;
            console.log("loadCityDetails");
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCityDetails", "Yogya")' + '?address_id=' + currentAddressID + '&person_id=' + currentPersonID + '&city_id=' +_cityid,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                 alert('Address Selected');                      
                   $("#CITY_DETAIL_AC").val(data.Data);

                }
            });
        },
```

Now, issue is that if i don't keep alert('Address Selected'); code in loadCityDetails, i am not getting city details loaded into city name field in form it comes only if alert is provided. But i don't want to keep this alert. So, how can i get city details loaded without displaying alert. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try to add `dataType: 'json'` in ajax

Comment: @user108 though added dataType: 'json', still the same problem, can't get city details...

Comment: what is return data ? put `console.log(data);`

Comment: return data is city details i.e. city name, state and country as can be seen in public JsonResult GetCityDetails() function shown at top and also getting correct value for that...

Comment: ok so you want to alert message only one time, now you can use  [jquery one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) i thing that will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the call to `$("#CITY_DETAIL_AC").val(data.Data);` happens in an async ajax-call, which runs independently of the DOM construction. You have no way of knowing if the DOM is ready by the time the function call returns - it probably isn't, since you can't access the element. Displaying the alert-box gives the system time to create the DOM before trying to write to it.

Solution:
Put the function containing the ajax call in .ready(), like this:

`$(document).ready(function(){..your function body here...});`

Then it's guaranteed not to happen before all elements are present. Now you will have to retrieve city-id from within the {...function body...}, as you can't expect it passed in as an argument anymore.

Comment: I already have it in  $(document).ready(function (){ } like this:$(document).ready(function () {
     
        $.extend
        ({  function defined here }); });